# Laravel 5: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've used laravel 5 for my project and everything was working fine until 2 days before but now I'm stuck with this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/.../public_html/CMS/vendor/compiled.php on line 9360
```

I've frontend and backend for this project and my frontend is working all fine without any errors. But when I log in to my backend, I can log in but just get a blank page. I don't find a way to get rid of this error. Please help me Thankyou.

Comment: This was happen on when time? Like when you login to your back end? So please include your login codes.

Answer (score 0):

What is your code exactly. Its eating up all the memory. Try optimizing your code. I will not prefer using this but it can be done for a temporary solution.

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```